# Delay notification in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-notifications

In order to develop a notification delay function, I plan to save the contents of the existing notification and send it as a new notification after a certain period of time (1 minute).

But why are new notifications sent twice from my phone? Also, how should I fix it?

class MyNotificationListener : NotificationListenerService() {

```
private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
private val delayedNotifications = mutableListOf<StatusBarNotification>()

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
    // UsageStatsServiceChannel 또는 현재 앱의 알림인 경우 무시
    if (sbn.notification.channelId == "UsageStatsServiceChannel") {
        return
    }
    if (sbn.notification.extras.getBoolean("isDelayedNotification", false)) {
        // This is a delayed notification, so we don't need to process it further
        return
    }

    if (isFeatureEnabled()) {
        cancelNotification(sbn.key)
        delayNotification(sbn)
    } else {
    }
}

private fun delayNotification(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
    // Save notifications to delay
    delayedNotifications.add(sbn)

    // Use handler to delay the notification
    handler.postDelayed({
        // Check if the notification still needs to be sent
        if (delayedNotifications.contains(sbn)) {
            sendDelayedNotification(sbn)
            delayedNotifications.remove(sbn)
        }
    }, 60000) // 1 minute delay
}

private fun sendDelayedNotification(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    val channelID = "delayed_channel_id"
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelID, "Delayed Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    val originalNotification = sbn.notification
    val packageName = sbn.packageName
    val smallIcon = sbn.notification.smallIcon
    val smallIconCompat = IconCompat.createFromIcon(this, smallIcon)

    val title = originalNotification.extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE) ?: "Notification"
    val text = originalNotification.extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT) ?: "No details available"
    val timestamp = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(Date(sbn.postTime))

    val contentIntent = originalNotification.contentIntent

    val newNotification = smallIconCompat?.let {
        NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelID)
            .setContentTitle("$title - $packageName")
            .setContentText("$text (Delayed: $timestamp)")
            .setSmallIcon(it) // Replace with your icon resource
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            // Add a unique identifier to extras
            .addExtras(Bundle().apply { putBoolean("isDelayedNotification", true) })
            .build()
    }
    val delayedNotificationId = generateUniqueNotificationId(sbn.id)
    notificationManager.notify(delayedNotificationId, newNotification)
}

private fun generateUniqueNotificationId(originalId: Int): Int {
    // Simple approach: Use a hash or a combination of the original ID and current time
    return originalId + System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()
}

private fun isFeatureEnabled(): Boolean {
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("ServiceEnabled", false)
}
```

}

Comment: You can only delay notifications when the app is in the foreground. For background notifications code will not work because os will handle notifications in that scenario.

Comment: I have already created a notification channel for the foreground service in another class.
Currently, all notifications are saved and a new notification is sent after 1 minute, which works well. But new notifications came twice and I started asking questions.